# Simple Code to get the SSID from Network

Tags: ios, networking, network-programming, ssid, captivenetwork

Hi I am Looking for a Simple Code to read the SSID, 
I found a lot of Information about "SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h"
but how can I use it, i don't understand it.
Sorry I am a new Objective-C programmer.
Do you have a good example or tutorial to understand it.
I tried Reachable from Apple but they don't work with Dictionaries.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @helming, here it is, this way it won't compile into the Simulator binary + added calls to CFRelease:

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    CFArrayRef interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef networkInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, 0));
    NSString *ssid = CFDictionaryGetValue(networkInfo, @"SSID");
    CFRelease(interfaces);
    CFRelease(networkInfo);
#endif
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i can get the ip Address from the Router,gateway?

Comment: For the ip, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
NSString *ssid = CFDictionaryGetValue(myDict, @"SSID");
```

Comment: Don't forget to release the copied Core Foundation objects, ARC won't take care of that for you. 

`CFRelease(myArray);
CFRelease(myDict);`

Comment: Also notice this does not work on the simulator, `CNCopySupportedInterfaces()` will return null

Comment: But how can i find the ipaddress for the router?

Comment: [dicInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ipaddr] forKey:@"IPAddress"];
https://github.com/bcsphere/wifi/blob/master/src/ios/BCWifi.m
Note: To test this you will need a device, simulator wouldn't work.