# How to get local ip address from ios device in asp.net c#?

Tags: ios, c#-4.0

Can i get a local ipaddress of ios device from asp.net? I want to get a ios device ip address and want to store into database.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the IP addresss using `ifaddrs`. Full example e.g. here: [iPhone/iPad/OSX: How to get my IP address programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically)

And than you can use web service (asmx or WCF) to send the IP address to your ASP.NET based service. An example e.g. here:

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/809_Consuming__NET_Web_Services_in_an_iOS_Application.aspx

UDPATE:

Based on your clarification, this is what you might need:

```
 Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"],   //the address, but if you are behind e.g. badly configured load balancer the IP will be not of the origin of the request
 Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] //if you are behind proxy or load balancer, this is where the original IP address should be
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. but i want to get using c# its possible to get in c#?

Comment: You mean Xamarin (former mono-touch)?

Comment: Not using former mono-touch,but i develop a ios web app in c# so i want to get local ip of ios device from where comes a request.So i want to do in c# asp.net