# How to detect IP address of a network interface changes in Swift on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, ip-address

I know the solution of doing it in C# on Windows.
NetworkChage.NetworkAddressChanged

I want to know how to do it in Swift on OSX
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ip address change notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378441/ip-address-change-notifications)

Comment: The `SystemConfiguration` framework (`SCDynamicStore`) provides APIs to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask