# How can I get the IP adress of my personal hotspot or other information in code

Tags: ios, iphone, ip, hotspot

I want to get the detail of my personal hotspot, such as the ip address, the device which connect to my hotspot. what's more, the information I communicate with other devices by my personal hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

Look around a little. As suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically):

Try this:

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress
{    
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    NSString *wifiAddress = nil;
    NSString *cellAddress = nil;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    if(!getifaddrs(&interfaces)) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            sa_family_t sa_type = temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family;
            if(sa_type == AF_INET || sa_type == AF_INET6) {
                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
                NSString *addr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)]; // pdp_ip0     
                NSLog(@"NAME: \"%@\" addr: %@", name, addr); // see for yourself

                if([name isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Interface is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                    wifiAddress = addr;    
                } else
                if([name isEqualToString:@"pdp_ip0"]) {
                    // Interface is the cell connection on the iPhone
                    cellAddress = addr;    
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
        // Free memory
        freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    }
    NSString *addr = wifiAddress ? wifiAddress : cellAddress;
    return addr ? addr : @"0.0.0.0";
}
```

Comment: actually I want know my personal hotspot's IP Address? by this function ,Do you know that?

Comment: I believe this works for every type of connection but personal hotspots. Why, I haven't looked into it yet...

Comment: Any solution for Personal hotspot ip address?