# iOS Hotspot find connected ip adresses

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

i currently looking for a way to find the IP adresses on a "host iphone" of the via hotspot connected devices.
Is there anway to do this in code/ on the iPhone it self?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023263/how-can-i-get-the-ip-adress-of-my-personal-hotspot-or-other-information-in-code

Comment: but there is no "no code" way right?