# iOS connected WIFI IP Address

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an application for IP Camera in iOS. Its a WIFI camera, through iPhone first I have to connect to the WIFI (there is no coding here, its normal phone to WIFI connection). After the WIFI is connected, I have to find the IP Address and then connect to the Camera, there will be two or more cameras connected with WIFI that means there will be more than 1 IP address. Can anyone tell me how to do it

Comment: Are you also developer of hardware of this camera or is it off the shelf product?

Comment: Does the camera support Bonjour?

Comment: this will helps u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically/10803584#10803584

Comment: It seems Axis cameras do support [Bonjour](https://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/) - you're in luck. Check out Apples code sample for discovering bonjour services on the network. Your cameras should show up running the sample code. Then you will have to learn how to filter the results and how to manage (dis)appearance of certain service (camera) on the network.

Comment: Thanks rokjarc I will check it out now

Comment: Sample code is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BonjourWeb/Introduction/Intro.html). There is quite a steep learning curve involved at first but it's usually worth the while.