# iPhone Connected WiFi Router's DHCP IP Address programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, dhcp

How to get the iPhone's connected WiFi Router's DHCP IP Address programmatically?

I am searching for the code which provide the currently connected WIFI Ip with which my iPhone is currently connected.

Comment: This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the link but this link will help to get my own iphone's ip address , but i want to get the connected wifi's ip address from my iphone. pl help me for this.

Comment: @AkashThakkar, Are you able to get WiFi Router's DHCP IP Address?