# STUN-iOS project can not show public IP

Tags: ios, stun

Now I have a problem with STUN protocol on iOS.
I downloaded the project on Github https://github.com/soulfly/STUN-iOS
However, when I running the project. It has just show log

`2015-06-19 15:55:08.245 STUN[4669:607] STUN server: stunserver.org
2015-06-19 15:55:08.247 STUN[4669:607] STUN Binding Request=<00010000 2112a442 ab8b1ef9 7347bf10 e98c817b>
2015-06-19 15:55:08.275 STUN[4669:607] STUN didSendDataWithTag=1002`

I can not show public IP that I need.

Please give me the advice to solve the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the reason why "STUN-iOS project" can not show public IP when we are running.

Reason: The server [stunsever.org](http://stunserver.org/) does not work.

Solution: In the file `STUNClient.h` you just change code `#define STUNServer @"stunserver.org"` to `#define STUNServer @"stun.services.mozilla.com"`. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *hostN = @"stunserver.org";
struct hostent* phot;
phot = gethostbyname(hostN.UTF8String);
if(phot) {
    struct in_addr ip_addr;
    memcpy(&ip_addr, phot->h_addr_list[0], 4);
    char *ip = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip_addr, ip, 20);
    NSString *ipStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:ip];
    free(ip);
    NSLog(@"ip:%@", ipStr);
}
```

and include some head file

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: However, I want to get public IP of my device. Could you help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically