# List of Wi-Fi networks in my App

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this app which is coded in Objective C. In my app there is a scenario in which I want to list out all the available Wi-Fi networks available to connect with my iPad. When I googled it I found out the private APIs are the only one option. Is there any other way with which I can show all the available Wi-Fi networks? I found a way to show the already connected WiFi connection name and details. But I want the Wi-Fi available connection list in my App. Thanks in advance. Happy Coding.

```
    NSString *wifiName = nil;
NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
for (NSString *ifnam in ifs)
{

    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);


    NSLog(@"info:%@",info);

    if (info[@"SSID"])
    {
        wifiName = info[@"SSID"];
        if(([wifiName rangeOfString:@"WA"].location == NSNotFound))
        {
            _textfield.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
            _textfield.text=@"";
            _textfield.hidden=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            _textfield.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            _textfield.text=wifiName;
            _textfield.hidden=NO;
```

Comment: then why cant you go through with those api you found, is any problem you facing ?

Comment: I haven't tried it but from the internet I read that using that may cause the app to get rejected.

Comment: i suggest you to check before you implement this kind of functionality, and your ques seems like opinion based we cant see any tried code here.

Answer (score 0):

U can list local Wifi like it's done [here](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan)

Or u can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5198716/2012219) question

The most interesting part is

```
struct ifaddrs {
    struct ifaddrs  *ifa_next;
    char        *ifa_name;
    unsigned int     ifa_flags;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_addr;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_netmask;
    struct sockaddr *ifa_dstaddr;
    void        *ifa_data;
};
```

where

```
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
NSString *addr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)]; // pdp_ip0


en0 is of type IEEE80211
en3 is of type Ethernet
en1 is of type Ethernet
en2 is of type Ethernet
bridge0 is of type Bridge
pdp_ip0 is of type cellular
utun0 is of type vpn
ipv4 is of type Ethernet
ipv6 is of type Ethernet
ap is of type accesPoint
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7072989/2012219) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30748480/2012219) can also be helpfull